# Printing a PDF page in A0 poster

Tags: print-design, posters, latex

I have a poster that I want to print in A0 size. For technical reasons, the output
PDF file unfortunately is currently not in A0 size. How can I print this poster in A0?

Should I first convert it to A0 somehow before sending it to the printer  (which I don't know how) or I can just send the file to the printer and there just simply select the A0 option in the printing menu and the printer would take care of it?

I have used LaTeX to make the poster.

Thanks

Comment: You could print it and Select 'Fit to Page' in the print settings. If it's all Vector, then no problem. If it's bitmap (jpeg or so) then - depending on the resolution of the file - it could get pixely. If that's the case I would at least open it in PS or Gimp and scale it to A0. The quality won't get better but the pixels will be smoothed out.

Comment: I see. Thank you! It's all vector graphics made in LaTeX. So I just take it to the store and hope that they don't ask for an A0 PDF. Hopefully it goes through.

Comment: BTW, when I scale it by gimp, it doesn't scale the PDF to fit the page. It simply makes a A0 canvas and puts the original PDF on top left cornor. So it adds a lot of white space on right side and bottom to fit it to A0 size.

Comment: if you have vectors I wouldnt use Gimp I would use [Inkscape](http://www.inkscape.org/en/)

Comment: Inkscape -->Object --> Transform --> Scale to A0 size. Save as PDF. The final output still comes out to be the original size, not A0 !

Comment: Hmm, I'm not an Inkscape user much but I just looked. In Inkscape -->Object --> Transform --> Scale you have the object(s) selected and you have mm (millimeters) chosen? And Scale proportionately checked?

Answer (score 2):

In my opinion, let the printing company study the document.

There are two main factors at hand.

**1)** Does the document have the correct proportion? Is the document A4 for example, and not a horizontal long banner-like document?

**2)** Is the document in vector format? If it has images, are they in a good enough resolution?

If the answer to those questions is yes, the printing company can simply check a box to fit the print to the page.

Just be sure to **tell the printing company** that you need them to print it on A0 84.1 × 118.9 cm. size.

---

P.S. Do not try to rescale it by yourself because you will potentially add some problems to the file, like resampling, changing color modes, etc. I read on the comments that you were trying to modify it on Gimp... Do not do that.

Answer (score 0):

As it is all vector graphics you can simply scale the PDF to the desired dimension:

There are several ways but the easiest way is using Print Production tool inside [Acrobat Pro](https://helpx.adobe.com/acrobat/kb/scale-or-resize-printed-pages.html#main_Manually_scale_using_percentages)

1. Open Preflight under Print Production
2. Click the wrench icon to get into the `Fixup Profiles`
3. Use the search field to find `Scale pages to specified size`
4. Hit the `Fix` button and type in the new dimensions

[image]

> Note: The new dimension might need to be larger than the A2 pending your file (does it include crop-marks etc?)

You can easily get the current trim and art dimensions with `Page does has not trimbox` profile.

[image]

Once you know the scale it might be easier to use the same `Fixup` but change the units to `percent`

[image]